# Call controller from another controller with object as a parameter and retrieve the response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two restcontrollers. Both are postmapping endpoints.

After the first controller (Controller1) makes everything i need witn an object, i would like to call/redirect the second controller in order to proceed and then get a response from it.

```java
@RestController
public class Controller1{

    @PostMapping("/endpoint1")
    public ReponseEntity<?> doWhatController1HasToDo(@RequestBody Object request){
       //some processing

       //here i would like to call second controller
    }
}
```

```java
@RestController
public class Controller2{

    @PostMapping("/endpoint2")
    public ReponseEntity<?> doWhatController2HasToDo(@RequestBody Object request){
       //some processing

       return new ResponseEntity<>(JSON, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I've tried using RestTemplate, but do get always 405 error. I've read somewhere, that it's because of the multipart

```java
private ResponseEntity forwardUsingRestTemplate(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, Object object) throws MalformedURLException {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity req = new HttpEntity(object, headers);
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<TdmResponse> response = template.exchange(getBaseUrl(httpServletRequest) + "/endpoint2", HttpMethod.POST, req, TdmResponse.class);
}
```

The question is, how do i call second endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you need to call another endpoint? Are these controllers in separate applications?

If not it's way more efficient to use a service on top of those 2 controllers:

```
public class Service {

 public Object processController1(Object object) {
 //some processing
 return processController2(result of some processing);
 }

 public Object processController2(Object object) {
 // processing
 }

}
```

And then in your controllers use these 2 methods:

```
public class Controller1{

    private Service service;

    public ReponseEntity<?> doWhatController1HasToDo(@RequestBody Object request){
       return new ResponseEntity<>(service.processController1(request), OK);
    }
}
```

```
public class Controller2{

    private Service service;

    public ReponseEntity<?> doWhatController1HasToDo(@RequestBody Object request){
       return new ResponseEntity<>(service.processController2(resultProcess1), OK);
    }
}
```

If there are 2 different applications then the problem might be your CSRF settings. If you have CSRF enabled in the second application then it will reject your call because you are not passing the CSRF token with RestTemplate.

Later Edit:

You can use the facade pattern to add another layer of abstraction between Controller and Services:

```
public class Facade{

    private Service1 service1;
    private Service2 service2;

    public ReponseEntity<?> doWhatController1HasToDo(@RequestBody Object request){
       Object resultService1 = service1.process(request);
       Object resultService2 = service2.process(resultService1);
       return new ResponseEntity<>(resultService2, OK);
    }

    public ReponseEntity<?> doWhatController2HasToDo(@RequestBody Object request){
       Object resultService2 = service2.process(request);
       return new ResponseEntity<>(resultService2, OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is, that services for each controller are pretty massive and i didn't want to mess them together

Comment: Then I would recommend you to use the "Facade" pattern! Basically, you add a new class in front of those 2 services. The facade will be called by the controllers. I've edited my response.

Answer (score 0):

You could also inject the second controller into the first controller and just call the method directly. This works if you don't want to change the endpoints dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is annotated with **@RestController** which means whatever is returned from controller methods are interpreted in the form of json or xml. In your case, if you return anything from *doWhatController1HasToDo* of Controller1, it will process this as json or xml. You should do this in following ways. It might help you.

```
@Controller
public class Controller1{

@PostMapping("/endpoint1")
public String doWhatController1HasToDo(@RequestBody Object request){
   //some processing

   return "redirect:/doWhatController2HasToDo";
} }
```

I am assuming, both your Controller are in same folder (i.e Controller1 and Controller2). This will call method **doWhatController2HasToDo(@RequestBody Object request)** of Controller2, and you can do anything into this method, like

```
@RestController
public class Controller2{

@PostMapping("/endpoint2")
public ReponseEntity<?> doWhatController2HasToDo(@RequestBody Object request){
   //some processing

   return new ResponseEntity<>(JSON, HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```